# Get PayPal transaction ID through data served by PayPal IPN (with REST API, not classic)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

The PayPal IPN serves the following data:

```
  'mc_gross' => '715.80',
  'protection_eligibility' => 'Eligible',
  'address_status' => 'unconfirmed',
  'item_number1' => '',
  'payer_id' => 'UCTG7GEULVxxx',
  'tax' => '0.00',
  'address_street' => 'Pl 2270',
  'payment_date' => '00:35:08 Jul 31, 2014 PDT',
  'payment_status' => 'Completed',
  'charset' => 'windows-1252',
  'address_zip' => '26492',
  'mc_shipping' => '0.00',
  'mc_handling' => '0.00',
  'first_name' => 'Benny',
  'mc_fee' => '8.94',
  'address_country_code' => 'SE',
  'address_name' => 'Benny Andersxxx',
  'notify_version' => '3.8',
  'custom' => '',
  'payer_status' => 'verified',
  'business' => 'paypal@xxx.com',
  'address_country' => 'Sweden',
  'num_cart_items' => '1',
  'mc_handling1' => '0.00',
  'address_city' => 'Klippan',
  'verify_sign' => 'AiJvJDl-VyZzRT4Hq0qB1wSjgCgGAvdLxvQHk79AHsO0AjdeWvSwxxx',
  'payer_email' => 'benny.anderxxx@xxx.com',
  'mc_shipping1' => '0.00',
  'tax1' => '0.00',
  'txn_id' => '1M112630L55146xxx',
  'payment_type' => 'instant',
  'last_name' => 'Andersxxx',
  'address_state' => '_0_',
  'item_name1' => 'Order xxx.com 2014-07-31',
  'receiver_email' => 'paypal@xxx.com',
  'payment_fee' => '',
  'quantity1' => '1',
  'receiver_id' => '4AMCEP9BMPxxx',
  'txn_type' => 'cart',
  'mc_gross_1' => '715.80',
  'mc_currency' => 'EUR',
  'residence_country' => 'SE',
  'transaction_subject' => '',
  'payment_gross' => '',
  'ipn_track_id' => '354021aeaxxx',
```

Is it possible getting through the information above to the transaction id which is required in quite a lot of other API transactions?

Actually, I'm trying to execute a refund via this call:

https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/{transactionId}/refund

However, I'm still missing the correct ID here and meanwhile I don't have any more ideas how to collect this transaction id (I guess it should look like ""PAY-PT597110X687430LKGECATA") ....

Please keep in mind that I'm using the REST API and not the classic API.

Edit: I don't know why, but every time I edit this article and add a "Hello" at the beginning, it is being deleted after saving :-( Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The transaction id is found on this line

> 'txn_id' => '1M112630L55146xxx',

You would need to call this URL with REST (sandbox URL shown, adjust for Live as needed)

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/refund/1M112630L55146xxx
```

You can see more details in the [API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#refunds)

Answer (score 0):

Just got a message from PayPal that refunds are only partially available wioth REST API. I'll now try it with Classic API...

However, it didn't work with the txn_id  @ Machavity